BART with all dummy features
I am trying to apply BART for classification in a problem where predictors are dummy variable as well as the y variable. I know is an uncommon set up but unfortunately this is the setting. Actually the 0 and 1 values were obtained from a categorical variable ranging from -4 to 4 setting the negative values to 0 add the positive values to 1. I also have the categorical version of the data in case it may be useful.
Now, my predictors contain a lot of NA values (namely 70%) and consist of a 648x48 matrix of dummies 0-1. My y variable does not contain missing values and has 648 values.
I am currently working in R with RStudio. When I perform the code below, however the result are disappointing:
bart_machine = build_bart_machine(predictors, response_var,use_missing_data = TRUE, use_missing_data_dummies_as_covars = TRUE)
bart_machine$confusion_matrix

Namely I obtain a NULL confusion matrix and
bartMachine v1.3.4.1 for regression

Missing data feature ON
training data size: n = 638 and p = 96 
built in 5.8 secs on 8 cores, 50 trees, 250 burn-in and 1000 post. samples

sigsq est for y beforehand: 0.016 
avg sigsq estimate after burn-in: 0.00314 

in-sample statistics:
 L1 = 9.91 
 L2 = 1.01 
 rmse = 0.04 
 Pseudo-Rsq = 0.9547
p-val for shapiro-wilk test of normality of residuals: 0 
p-val for zero-mean noise: 0.99451 

Now my questions are:

do you think that I have too many NA values in order to perform a BART?

Do you think my set up should at least produce a confusion matrix?

Do you think that the categorical version of the data may be more helpful here or the disappointing results above are due to something more profound?


EDIT: I have actually performed predictions but they are quite disappointing:
# Extract the feature names
feature_names <- bart_machine[["training_data_features_with_missing_features"]]

# Remove the "M_" prefix
feature_names <- gsub("^M_", "", feature_names)

# Update the bart_machine object with the renamed feature names
bart_machine[["training_data_features_with_missing_features"]] <- feature_names


# Inspect feature names in bart_machine training data
training_data <- bart_machine[["model_matrix_training_data"]]
training_feature_names <- colnames(training_data)

# Remove the "M_" prefix from the column names
training_feature_names <- gsub("^M_", "", training_feature_names)

# Update the bart_machine object with the renamed columns
colnames(training_data) <- training_feature_names
bart_machine[["model_matrix_training_data"]] <- training_data

# Impute missing data in albany2005_predictors using the same method
imputed_data_2005 <- mice(albany2005[, -1], m = 5, method = 'pmm', maxit = 50, seed = 500)
complete_data_2005 <- complete(imputed_data_2005, 1)

# Remove the "M_" prefix from the column names in albany2005_predictors
colnames(complete_data_2005) <- gsub("^M_", "", colnames(complete_data_2005))

# Ensure albany2005_predictors has the same columns as the training data, excluding 'y_remaining'
required_cols <- setdiff(training_feature_names, "y_remaining")
albany2005_predictors <- complete_data_2005[, required_cols, drop = FALSE]



# Create a logical vector for non-NA values in albany2005_response
non_na_indices <- !is.na(albany2005_response)

# Subset predicted_values and albany2005_response using non_na_indices
non_na_predicted_values <- predicted_values[non_na_indices]
non_na_actual_values <- albany2005_response[non_na_indices]


# Predict using the bartMachine model on the 2005 data
predicted_values <- predict(bart_machine, albany2005_predictors, type = "class")

# Calculate RMSE
# Convert predicted values to numeric
non_na_predicted_values <- as.numeric(as.character(non_na_predicted_values))

# Convert actual values to numeric
non_na_actual_values <- as.numeric(as.character(non_na_actual_values))

rmse <- sqrt(mean((non_na_predicted_values - non_na_actual_values)^2))

# Print the RMSE
print(paste("RMSE: ", rmse)). ###very high RMSE!!!


I am looking at ?build_bart_machine and don't see confusion_matrix as one of the output components, which is probably why it is NULL (e.g. bart_machine$not_a_real_component is also NULL). It seems that running summary(bart_machine) might give you a confusion matrix? The model seems to have a low error and high R^2 though, why do you say the results are disappointing?

Read ?bartMachine::summary.bartMachine. A confusion matrix is returned only if the model is for classification. If the model "is for regression, the summary L1, L2, rmse, Pseudo-R^2
, R^2
are printed as well as the p-value for the tests of normality and zero-mean noise.". Given your output your model is for regression.

A BART model for classification is fitted only if the response is a factor with 2 levels. If you have a dummy as the response, coerce to factor first.

I see. Thank you. Sorry for the question. The problem is that by reading the seminal paper of the package is that they did not implement a method for classification back at the time. Do you think in general that my set up is a good one for using BART?
